# How to truncate the lines to specific length in a file which occurs between specific patterns?

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have multiple files in which I have to truncate only the lines which comes between pattern @TEST and enabled="true">. When there is a match, the string between `@TEST` and `enabled="true">` should be only 50 characters. All other lines should be left intact.

Example:

> @TEST-TC_0010 @TEST Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should not
>   send the Accounting-Response Message on Receiving  the
>   Accounting-Request Packet from the RADIUS Client" enabled="true">

I have to change above line as shown below.

@TEST-TC_0010 **@TEST** Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should not **enabled="true">**

Comment: What is (**exactly**) your desired output? Do you want to **remove** the characters that are `X`?

Comment: I have multiple lines in a file which appears like  "@TEST-TC_0010@TEST Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should not send the Accounting-Response Message on Receiving the Accounting-Request Packet from the RADIUS Client" enabled="true">.  The content of each such lines are different only common thing in those lines are @TEST & enabled="true">. I want to truncate the line between these pattern to 50 char.So if you see the above line I want to actually truncate this Verify that the XXXXX XXXXX server should not send the Response Message on Receiving the Request Packet from the XXX Client

Comment: (1) Are you saying that you have some long lines (nearly 200 characters) that (always) contain `@TEST` twice at and/or near the beginning and `enabled="true">` at or near the end?  When you say “all the lines which occur between pattern1 and pattern2,” people are going to think that line 20 contains pattern1, line 25 contains pattern2, and you want to do something to lines 21-24.  (2) Why does the last line of your question have all those X characters?  (3) Show an example of your desired output.  (9) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense as currently stated. Please reword carefully (click on the "edit" link below the question) and possibly add a couple more lines of input and the expected output.

Comment: Voting to close until and unless the OP clarifies what they're trying to do.

Comment: @Shadur . I have updated the question.

Comment: @Beginner:  It's getting better.  Your first paragraph is still confusing, as per my comment.  rcjohnson's edit made it clearer; why did you trample on his (or her?) wording?  Your example output is good; that's the sort of thing we've been asking for.  But "Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should not" is 51 characters, and, by my understanding of the question, we should count the spaces before and after as well, for a total of 53 characters, so I don't understand how this example matches your question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use grep with Perl lookarounds.

```
grep -oP '(?<=@TEST ).*(?=\" enabled=\"true\")' inputfile
```

The expression "(?<=)" marks the point at which a match will begin and the expression "(?=)" is the point at which the match ends.

The ".*" tells grep to return everything between the begin and end points.

Using your test input, the line above returns 157 characters.

```
$ echo "Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should not send the Accounting-Response Message on Receiving the Accounting-Request Packet from the RADIUS Client" | wc -m
157
```

If you want to further truncate this to only the first 50 characters, you can use cut

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=@TEST ).*(?=\" enabled=\"true\")' inputfile | cut -c1-50
Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should no
```

If you wish to save the results to a file then you need to pipe the output into another file. You can use something like the following...

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=@TEST ).*(?=\" enabled=\"true\")' inputfile | cut -c1-50 >> outputfile
```

Overwriting the input file is not something I'd personally recommend since you might need to use the original data at some point.

So if you need to keep all other entries in the file and truncate only those lines in which enabled="true", we need to change tools to awk.

```
$ awk  -F'@TEST' '{if (/true/) print substr($3,2,50); else print $0}' inputfile >> outputfile
```

This oneliner will output, without change, every line that does not match true. When true is matched, then the line will be truncated to 50 characters. Again I do not recommend overwriting the original data so the results are piped into an outputfile.

Based on the most recent edits made to the question by the OP, I modified the awk one-liner to replicate the output Beginner provided. He mentioned in his comment that awk does not work. Until the OP provides more details as to why awk does not work, when using awk 4.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 the following line will return the results he has detailed thus far.

```
awk  -F'@TEST' '{if (/true/) print "@TEST"$2,"@TEST",substr($3,2,50),"enabled=\"true\">"; else print $0}' inputfile >> outputfile
```

Comment: Thank You for your comment, can you please explain how it is truncating the line to 50 char ? I am not able to understand that . Thanks in Adv

Comment: Thank you so much, can you just help me with how can I save the truncated line to the same file instead of printing it.

Comment: Directing the output of Grep to a new file is only capturing the truncated output, but my requirement is to truncate the sentence in the same file without changing all the other content of the file .Example:-change  @TEST-TC_0010@TEST Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should not  send the Accounting-Response Message on Receiving  the Accounting-Request Packet from the RADIUS Client" enabled="true"> to @TEST-TC_0010@TEST Verify that the RADIUS accounting server should not  send" enabled="true">

Comment: awk doesn't work.